# AWS IoT search for dynamic Thing Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I would like to find a list of dynamic thing groups. I can see the type of field when I go to one of the thing groups in AWS IoT Core. How do I search and find a list of thing groups which has a `Type` as `Dynamic`?

e.g.

When I visit one of the Thing Group present in IoT Core.

```
You do not have a description for the thing group yet.

Created
Jul 26, 2019 11:21:44 AM -0700

Type
Static

0 Attributes
```

I tried a few variants, but they did not work.

```
Type: Dynamic
attributes.Type: Dynamic
Type == Dynamic
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is not straight-forward. Thanks to my colleague, I created a script to get that list.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('iot')

list_thing_groups = client.list_thing_groups()
while True:
    for thing_group in list_thing_groups['thingGroups']:
        name = thing_group['groupName']
        response = client.describe_thing_group(
            thingGroupName=name
        )
        query = response.get('queryString')
        if query:
            print(name)
    if list_thing_groups.get('nextToken'):
        list_thing_groups = client.list_thing_groups(nextToken=list_thing_groups.get('nextToken'))
    else:
        break
```

The idea is `queryString` for dynamic Thing Group won't be null.

Answer (score 1):

- Configure a [Thing Group index on Fleet Indexing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/thinggroup-index.html).
- For every dynamic Thing Group created, add an attribute to distinguish it as a dynamic thing group, i.e. `attribute.dynamic: true`
- Call SearchIndex on the index with the query `attributes.dynamic: true` and that will return all dynamic Thing Groups.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. We have 100s of things groups and it is not possible when those have been already created.